# IllegalDataException while parsing special character

Tags: xml, encoding, jdom

I have an input box in my web app, If I type the following input:

**char ʃƪ**

on server side when I try to build an xml doc using Jdom it crashes raising the following exception:

**org.jdom.IllegalDataException: The data "char (3A" is not legal for a JDOM attribute: 0x1a is not a legal XML character.**

```
     at org.jdom.Attribute.setValue(Attribute.java:491)      
     at org.jdom.Attribute.<init>(Attribute.java:228)
     at org.jdom.Attribute.<init>(Attribute.java:251)
     at org.jdom.Element.setAttribute(Element.java:1128)
```

this is how the browser encodes the ajax call
...**&MESSAGE=char%20(3%1AA**

on server side when I do
**pRequest.getParameter("MESSAGE");**
it returns me: "**char (3A**"

Any ideas what's going on there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is working now.

I switched from the jQuery plug-in URLEncode to the native javascript function:

```
encodeURIComponent()
```

Moreover I found out that in an ajax call you can specify the contentType

```
contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
```

Answer (score 0):

The XML 1.0 Spec does not allow for the character 0x1a to be used... ever. It is *not* a unicode character

http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/PER-xml-20080205/#charsets

The XML 1.1 spec *does* allow the 0x1a character, I see: http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xml11-20040204/#NT-Char

Three things though:

- JDOM 1.x (and 2.x) will reject non-XML1.0 characters.
- Even in XML 1.1, the 0x1a char is 'Restricted' (I am not 100% sure what that means yet, I am investigating).
- Are you certain that you *want* to be using the 'Substitution' character (0x1a)

Regardless of the the above, I suspect that you have a problem in your code between the input box and the JDOM setAttribute(...) call. Is there something between these places that is changin the character encoding, serializing, or otherwise altering the input value? I would suspect that there is some other problem happening before JDOM is called that is altering the data, since it is not likely that you are really trying to load the char 0x1a as an XML character.

Answer (score 0):

As @rolfl is suspecting, something is very weired in your browser. What are you using?

If we do a little Unicode and encoding detective work, we can get a hint on what's probably going on.

Assuming you are trying to enter these characters:

- ʃ, Unicode U+0283 (latin small letter esh)
- ƪ, Unicode U+01AA (latin letter reversed esh loop)

We can see that the browser encoding is stemming from the unicode code point for these two characters:

- (, happens to be 28 in the ascii character set
- 3, the remaining 3
- %1A, 1A is not a legal URL character so it is encoded
- A, the remaining A

Is it some ajax javascript library youare using? Perhaps time to switch?